# how to distinguish the user database to login with the product database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I have two databases for admin login and also product database. but when i check in postman database for product it mixes with admin database.[users database for admin and databengkel for product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMPwJ.jpg)
but when i add data for product the data goes into database **users**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the database from the input product data is mixed with the database login users